# An error was thrown in afterAll ReferenceError: module is not defined, Karma/Jasmine test error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I'm trying to write tests for m nodejs simple application with karma and jasmine as a framework. I'm using karma-coverage for preprocessor.
Here is the structure of the project:
[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "tests with karma in jasmine framework",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat Aug 17 2019 09:37:53 GMT+0500 (Uzbekistan Standard Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'js/*.js',
            'test/*.test.js'
        ],


        // list of files / patterns to exclude
        exclude: [],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'test/*.test.js': ['coverage']
        },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity,

        // optionally, configure the reporter
        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'html',
            dir: 'coverage/'
        }
    })
}
```

Whenever I run `npm test` I'm getting the following error:

[image]

**custom-lodash.js**

```
class CustomLodash {

    compact(array) {
        let newArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (!array[i] || array[i] === undefined || array[i] === null) {
                continue;
            }

            this.push(array[i])(newArray);
        }
        return newArray;
    }


}

let _ = new CustomLodash;

module.exports = {
    compact: _.compact
};
```

**custom-lodash.test.js**

```
describe("CustomLodash", function () {

    let utils;
    //This will be called before running each spec
    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log('before each');
        utils = new CustomLodash();
    });


    describe("when calc is used to peform basic math operations", function () {
        it("creates an array with all falsey values removed", function () {
            // expect(utils.compact([0, 1, false, 2, '', 3])).toBe([1, 2, 3]);
            let compact = utils.compact([0, 1, false, 2, '', 3]);
            console.log('before each in it is: ', compact);
            expect(compact).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
           //console.log('is defined ', expect(compact).toEqual([1, 2, 3]));
        });
    })


});
```

As you can see, the `console.log` is giving output, which means the file is being read. But, when I call `toBe()` or `toEqual()` I can see that the output is undefined (checked this in `console.log` too). 
Any help is really **appreciated**. I searched for many answers and realted questions, but can't fix this one.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share with my solution to this case.

Adding browserify worked for me. Also, I added watchify to watch files for incremental compilation.

> Browserify was born to make your Node code in the browser. Till date
>   it only supports the node flavour of commons (including JSON support)
>   and provides in-built shims for many node core modules. Everything
>   else is a different package.

Here is how my `package.json` looks like after adding packages to run my ES6 code both in browser and Node:

```
"dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.3.0",
    "karma-commonjs": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1"
    "watchify": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

Don't forget to add browserify in your `karma.config.js` configuration as follows:

- add it to your frameworks list
- add it your preprocessors list.

Example:

```
preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
      'js/**/*.js': ['browserify'],
      'test/**/*.[sS]pec.js': ['browserify']
    }
```

One can solve this kind of problem with ES6 by building `webpack`, but as `browserify` is much more likely to work with minimal configuration I chose using it as a solution in this situation. Hope it will help someone.